# Assigning refs to Vue 3 components after the parent has mounted

Tags: vue.js, async-await

I have a Vue component like this:

```js
<script setup>
// ...imports

const entries = ref([]);
const entryComponentsRefs = ref([]);

onMounted(async () => {
  entries.value = await fetchEntries()
});
</script>

<template>
  <Container>
    <Entry v-for="entry in entries" :key="entry.id" ref="entryComponentsRefs" />
  </Container>
</template>
```

Now, I want to implement an entry search that would autoscroll the `<Container>` to the selected search result, using the entry's `ref`. But `entryComponentsRefs` remains empty even after `entries` is already populated and the `<Entry>`'s already show up.

Is there anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your data you need to wait Vue to update DOM:

https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick

```
onMounted(async () => {
  entries.value = await fetchEntries()
  await nextTick();
  // do your DOM work here
});
```

Comment: [just some additional info] prepending `:` in front of a property in the template of a vue SFC is a shorthand for using [`v-bind:`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind).

Comment: It's a typo. I'm already using `ref=entryComponentRefs` in `<Entry>`"

Comment: It's not that my DOM isn't updating, I'm still trying to get `entries.value` to populate. After the entries are fetched and `<Entry>` components showing up, `entries` still empty